# How do I access the default export of a module imported via a Webpack dynamic import promise?

Tags: javascript, class, webpack, import, module

Question says it all. Googling returns plenty of examples of ES6 import syntax, but I'm using a Webpack "dynamic import". In the below code, I've shown my consumer file with commented results:

Module file:

```
export default class Main {
  init() {
    console.log("Main init");
  }
}
```

Consumer file:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "main" */ "./main").then(Main => {
  init(Main);
});
function init(Main) {
console.log(Main); // "Module"
const main = new Main.Main(); // not a constructor
const main = new Main(); // not a constructor
const main = new Main.getDefault(); // not a constructor
}
```

Comment: In the init function I also tried another ES6 import {Main} from Main; but I got an error during my Webpack build that "import can only be used at the top level"

Comment: What's your console output when you logged the `Main` in `then`? Did you get the class?

Comment: "Module". Still experimenting ...

Answer (score 0):

I needed to access the module default like:

```
const mainclass = Main.default;
const main = new mainclass();
```